# Alarm System in 2008 HHR Keeps Alarming After Battery Test

Tags: battery, chevrolet, alarm, hhr

I have an 2008 HHR and after a battery test by machine, my alarm system continued to go off all through the night. Does the battery cables or tester have anything to do with the alarm system? Seven days later the battery went completely dead.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Is the alarm system OEM or aftermarket? Was the battery removed for testing?